# Numeric integration problem in a quadrotor vertical descend code

Tags: control, quadcopter

I'm trying to implement a drone in vertical descend. As for maximum simplification, I maintain all its angles to 0, and just try to get to the my desired descend. However, when I debug, I see that my z_acel variable changes value when it comes to the velocity integration. And obviously cant reach to my desired height, which is 10cm below. Anyone can help?

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpmath import *


#***DRONES****

#Dynamic parameters
L=25 
b = 1e-5 
I = np.diag([5e-7, 5e-7, 10e-7]) 
k=3e-5
m=0.5
kd=0.25
#PID Values
Kp, Ki, Kd = 4.05, 0, 20.64 
g=9.80
dt=0.1

#variables inicialization
N=500
phi_acel= angulotheta_acel= psi_acel= [0] * N
phi_vel= angulotheta_vel= psi_vel= [0]*N
phi = angulotheta = psi = [0]*N
z= z_vel= z_acel= [0]*N
Torque=inputs=[0]*4

height_objective=-10 #reach from 0 to -10cm height.

for i in range(2,N):

   #HEIGHT CONTROLLER
   err_height=height_objective-z[i-1]

   Torque[0]=err_height*Kp + err_height*Ki*dt - (z_vel[i-1]-z_vel[i-2])*Kd*dt + (m*g)/(math.cos(phi[i-1])*math.cos(angulotheta[i-1])) 
   if Torque[0]>20:
       Torque[0]=20
   elif Torque[0]<0:
       Torque[0]=0


   z_acel[i]= -g + (math.cos(angulotheta[i-1])*math.cos(phi[i-1]))*Torque[0]/m  #with all the angles zero, z_acel[i] should be -g = -9.8

   z_vel[i]= z_vel[i-1] + z_acel[i]/2*dt   #however, in this step, the z_acel[i] changes the value

   z[i]= z[i-1] + z_vel[i]/2*dt

   plt.plot(i,z[i],'or')
   plt.pause(0.1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i got the answer. When I inicialize the variables, I wrote $z= z_v= z_a= [0]*N, $, even I thought it had no more influence in the code, it has. As it is written now the code, the value of z_vel is the new value for z_acel in every iteration.